# Why are the inputs to my guess_nonlinear() all 1s?

Tags: default, solver, openmdao, order-of-execution

The N2 diagram for my full problem is below.
[image: Full N2 diagram]
The N2 diagram for the coupled portion of the problem is below.
[image: Coupled N2]
I have a DirectSolver handling the coupling between LLTForces and ImplicitLiftingLine, and an LNBGS solver handling the coupling between LiftingLineGroup and TestCL.

The gist for the problem is here: https://gist.github.com/eufren/31c0e569ed703b2aea3e2ef5360610f7

I have implemented guess_nonlinear() on ImplicitLiftingLine, which should use various outputs from LLTGeometry to give a good initial guess for the vortex strengths based on a linearised form of the governing equations.

```
def guess_nonlinear(self, inputs, outputs, resids):
    freestream_unit_vector = inputs['freestream_unit_vector']
    freestream_velocity = inputs['freestream_velocity']
    n = inputs['normal_vectors']
    A = inputs['surface_areas']
    l = inputs['bound_vortices']
    ic_tot = inputs['influence_coefficients_total']

    v_inf = freestream_velocity
    v_inf_vec = v_inf*freestream_unit_vector

    lin_numerator = np.pi * v_inf * A * np.sum(n * v_inf_vec, axis=1)
    lin_denominator = (np.linalg.norm(np.cross(v_inf_vec, l), axis=1) - np.pi * v_inf * A * np.sum(np.sum(n * ic_tot, axis=2), axis=1))
    lin_vtx_str = lin_numerator / lin_denominator

    outputs['vortex_strengths'] = lin_vtx_str
```

However, when the problem is run for the first time, any inputs not explicitly set with p.set_val() are all 1s. This causes guess_nonlinear() to give a bad output and so the system fails to converge:
[image]

As far as I can tell, the execution order for the LLT group is correct, and the geometry components should be being executed before the implicit component. I'm confused as to why this doesn't seem to actually be happening when the code is run, and instead these inputs are taking their default values.

What do I need to change to get this to work properly? Additionally, I've found difficulty in getting LNBGS to converge (hence adding guess_nonlinear()) during optimisation - only DirectSolver gets all the way through the optimisation without issues, but it's very slow for large numbers of LLT nodes). How can I improve the linear and nonlinear solver selection, and improve the reliability of the iterative solver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: Thanks for providing a testable example. It made figuring out the answer to your question a lot simpler. Your problem was a bit subtle and I would not have been able to give a good answer without runnable code*

Your first question: "Why are all the inputs 1"

**"Short" Answer**
You have put the nonlinear solver to high in the model hierarchy, which then included a key precurser component that computed your input values. By moving the solver down to a lower level of the model, I was able to ensure that the precurser component (`LTTGeometry`) ran and had valid outputs before you got to the `guess_nonlinear` of implicit component.

Here is what you had (Notice the implicit solver included `LTTGeometry` even though the data cycle does not require that component: [image: n2 of bad solver structure]

I moved both the nonlinear solver and the linear solver down into the `LTTCycle` group, which then allows the `LTTGeometry` component to execute before getting to the nonlinear solver and `guess_nonlinear` step:
[image]

My fix is only partially correct, since there is a secondary cycle from the `TestCL` component that also needs a solver and does not have one. However, that cycle still does not involve the `LTTGeometry` group. So the fully correct fix is to restructure you model top run geometry first, and then put the `LTTCycle` and `TestCL` groups together so you can run a solver over just them. That was a bit more hacking than I wanted to do on your test problem, but you can see the general idea from the adjusted N2 above.

**Long Answer**
The `guess_nonlinear` sequence in OpenMDAO does **NOT** run the compute method of explicit components or of groups. It follows the execution hierarchy, and calls any `guess_nonlinear` that it finds. So that means that any explicit components you have in your model will **NOT** get executed, their outputs will not get updated with computed values, and those computed values will not get passed to the inputs of downstream components.

Things get a little tricky when you have deep model hierarchies. The `guess_nonlinear` method is called as the first step in the nonlinear solver process. If you have a NonLinearRunOnce solver at the top level, it will follow the compute chain down the line calling `compute` or `solve_nonlinear` on each child and doing a data transfer after each one. If one of those children happens to be a group with a nonlinear solver, then that solver will call `guess_nonlinear` on its children (grandchildren of the top group with the NonLinearRunOnce solver) as the first step. So any outputs that were computed by the siblings of this group will be valid, but none of the outputs from the grandchild level will have been computed yet.

You may be wondering why not just have the `guess_nonlinear` method call the compute for any explicit components? There is a difficult to balance trade off here. If you assume that all explicit components are very cheap to run, then it *might* make sense to run the compute methods --- or it might not. A lot depends on the cyclic data structure. If some early component in the group needs guesses from the later one, then running its compute isn't going to help you much at all. Perhaps more importantly though, not all explicit components are cheap to run. You might have a very expensive computation, and calling compute as part of the guess process would be way too costly.

The compromise here, if you need some kind of top level guess process, is that you can [implement `guess_nonlinear` at the group level](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/3.9.2/features/core_features/grouping_components/guess_method.html). It's less common to do, but it gives you total control over what happens. You can call whatever you need to call in whatever sequence.

So the absolute key thing to remember is that the only data you have available to you when a `guess_nonlinear` is called is any data that was computed before your containing solver was executed. That means any thing that was computed before you got to the model scope of the containing solver (not the scope of the component with the `guess_method` itself).

Your second question: "How can I speed this up when the number of nodes gets large?"

This one not possible to give a generic answer to at all. I noticed that you have already specified sparse partial derivatives. That is a great start, but if its still not fast enough for you then it means you're reaching the limits of what you can do with a DirectSolver. You note that this solver is the only one that gets you through the optimization without issues, which I will take to mean that ScipyKrylov[enter link description here](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/3.9.2/features/building_blocks/solvers/linear/scipy_iter_solver.html) and [PetscKrylov](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/3.9.2/features/building_blocks/solvers/linear/petsc_krylov.html) are not converging the linear system well for you --- at least not by themselves. Thats not surprising, as krylov solvers almost always require some kind of preconditioner... and this is why I can't offer a generic answer. Setting up efficient linear solvers for larger-scale compute is a tricky subject. If you look into the literature, you'll find some good suggestions. You can also study open source implementations like [VSPAero](https://github.com/OpenVSP/OpenVSP/tree/main/src/vsp_aero/solver) for some tips.

effectively, you've reached the limit of what simple linear solvers can offer you. From this point forward, OpenMDAO can help a bit by making it easier to implement some preconditioning, but you'll have to suffer the math side yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried implementing your suggestion by specifying DirectSolver as the linear solver in LLTCycle, and NewtonSolver as the nonlinear solver in LLTCycle. I've set up a subgroup (Cycle2D3D) in LiftingLineTestGroup, which contains LLTCycle and TestCl. I have set LinearBlockGS as the linear solver for Cycle2D3D, and NonlinearBlockGS as the nonlinear solver. 

It seems like guess_nonlinear is running correctly now. However, when I debug and look at compute() in TwoDForces, it seems like Cl isn't being updated at each iteration. I presume this is a solver problem.

Comment: Unsetting the nonlinear solver for LLTCycle and setting the nonlinear solver for Cycle2D3D to NewtonSolver with solve_subsystems=True does seem to update the Cl values, but then it pretty quickly diverges. I'm confident that the code for the analysis itself is correct, and I'd just like to rule out any mistakes I'm making with the problem setup in OpenMDAO before I try to figure out how to help the linear solver converge.

The gist for my attempt to add your fix is here: https://gist.github.com/eufren/8e8592510b96f98e4f5604951ba8bbbf

Let me know if this would be better as a new question.

Comment: the case you provided there ran and converged with no issues. As given it had `run_model` in the script. Did you mean that it diverged when you called `run_driver`? Regardless, there is a lot going on in this model. If you have questions about stabilizing the solver, try to reduce the model down to just the specific case (or cases) you're asking about. Pull the group with the solver out and into its own model file. Give inputs and a run script that show the problem. You can use the debug_printing options on solvers to help capture relevant inputs and make a test case.

Comment: `run_driver`, yes. I'll see if I can get a better description of how it diverges.